# Copy tables from one database to another using Alteryx

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database, google-cloud-sql, alteryx

I have a list of tables that need to copied from one database to another. The list of tables resides in the table in a DB. I am trying to write a Standard Macro to perform this. This is what I have so far:

[image]

The macro reads the in list of tables and then reads that using the Dynamic Input. But I am unsure how to write the tables to the second DB. Please advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a batch macro where each batch will bring in a different table. The Dynamic Input tool will not work because the tables are of different schemas.

The workflow will have a Control Parameter (set to the table name) and updating an Input Data tool. This will then go to an Output Tool that has the "Take File/Table Name from field" option selected.